# Forward Mysql logs to Syslog-ng

Tags: mysql, syslog

Ubuntu 10.04

I have set MySQL to log slow queries and a general mysql log.  How can I pipe those files in syslog to forward to centralized logging service (which is working)?  Tried:

```
source s_mysql_instance_1 {
    pipe("/var/log/mysql/mysql.log" );
};
log { 
     source(s_mysql_instance_1); destination(d_loggly); 
};
```

Get:

```
Error opening file for reading; filename='/var/log/mysql/mysql.log', error='Permission denied (13)'
Error initializing source driver; source='s_mysql_instance_1', id='s_mysql_instance_1#0'
Error initializing message pipeline;
```

I have also disabled apparmor and still get the same results

Answer (score 0):

Either the `'/var/log/mysql/mysql.log'` file doesn't exist (the default on my 12.04 machine is just `/var/log/mysql.log`), or the user that's performing this operation doesn't have access to it and needs to be granted read permission.

Comment: Ewan, The file does exist.  So I thought it was a permissions but syslog-ng runs as root so there shouldn't be any permission problems right?  Any other ideas?